Can MySQL Accept DDNS for Group Replication Setup?
I'm currently setting up MySQL Group Replication between a local server and a cloud server.
However, the local server doesn't have a static IP address, so I'm considering using Dynamic DNS (DDNS) for the local server addresses.

Is it feasible to use DDNS for the local server in a MySQL Group
Replication setup?
What are the potential issues or errors I might encounter when using
DDNS instead of a static IP address for MySQL Group Replication?

MySQL Version: 8.0.38
DDNS Provider: no-ip
